# Access values from one Google Sheet in another

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

I need some values from Spreadsheet 2 (in Tab 2) in Spreadsheet 1 (in Tab 1).

[image: Tab 1 and Tab 2]

I don’t know the URL for each Spreadsheet; they are unknown.

How can I switch between these Tabs and get the values from Spreadsheet 2?

Is there a command for Google Apps Script?

Comment: Did you try `importrange` ?

Comment: That wouldn´t work for my task.

Comment: I create some new Spreadsheets and I need their values in a Master-Template-Spreadsheets. Therefore Importrange is not a good solution.

Comment: Welcome. Please follow the [tour], read [ask] and add a brief description of your search/research efforts. Also please clarify what you mien by "Tabs" (are this spreadsheets or sheets?, have you already read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets?)

Comment: When you want to reword a question that was not already answered, please [edit] that question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Do you know the spreadsheets name or id? Are the spreadsheets in a folder?

Comment: I know the Name but not the ID or URL from the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet is in a folder and I also know the name and the URL from the folder.

Comment: Okay, I had tried a step when I know both ID´s.

Comment: And that is my first try:

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kEYM2FLO1x3LlRyTjQgZJHPNSoV_bhWSRWzu435fsRo").getSheetByName("Design Solution").getRange('A2:G10').getValue();
 
 SpreadsheetApp.openById("1YlEEfukZVD0k0nMBhLRmvCXbbKMsxB4lXy4d1PL4wFI").getSheetByName("Tabelle1").getRange('A2').setValue();

Comment: But it doesn´t work. Does there exist a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your script can be resolved with a couple of simple changes in syntax

- `getValue();` - you should assign this result to a variable so that you can use the variable to the `setValue()` on the other spreadsheet
- `getValue` Vs `getValues` - `getValue` returns a single value (the value of the top-left cell in the range); by comparison `getValues` returns the rectangular grid of values for the range. Even though you specified the range as "A2:G10" by using `getValue` you only returned the value in cell A2. If you wanted the values in every cell of the range you should have used `getValues`
- `setValue` Vs `setValues` - the same rule works for setting values - `setValue` sets a single value, and `setvalues` sets a rectangular grid of values (and must match dimensions of `getValues` range).
- `setValue(sourceValue)` - you need to specify the value(s) that are to be set. This is the reason why you assign the `getValue` method to a variable. That variable is used here to define the value that is to be set.

---

```
  var sourcess = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kEYM2FLO1x3LlRyTjQgZJHPNSoV_bhWSRWzu435fsRo");
  var sourceValue = sourcess.getSheetByName("Design Solution").getRange('A2').getValue();
  var targetss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1YlEEfukZVD0k0nMBhLRmvCXbbKMsxB4lXy4d1PL4wFI");
  targetss.getSheetByName("Tabelle1").getRange('A2').setValue(sourceValue);
```